# Access-Control-Allow-Origin blocking my post but I allowed it

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express

Hello as the title said I actually have 2 endpoint the first one is working:

```
app.get("/posts", (request, response) => {
  response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  let posts = [];
  db.collection("posts")
    .orderBy("date", "desc")
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        posts.push(doc.data());
      });
      response.send(posts);
    });
});
```

But I have a second one to post that is not working:

```
app.post("/createPost", (request, response) => {
  response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  response.send(request.headers);
});
```

This one show me the following error:

''Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/createPost' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.''

I don't understand because I allow cross origin the same way in both endpoints, thanks if you take the time to read me and help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

```
npm i cors
```

on `app.js`

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```